# Error using += to append a Character to a String: String is not identical to UInt8

Tags: swift, ios8

When trying to use the `+=` operator to append a `Character` to a `String`, I'm getting the following error:

> String is not identical to UInt8

The error occurs on the `puzzleOutput += char` line in the code below:

```
let puzzleInput = "great minds think alike "
var puzzleOutput = ""

for char in puzzleInput
{
    switch char
    {
    case "a","e","i","o","u":
        continue

    default:
       puzzleOutput += char
    }
}

println(puzzleOutput)
```

How can I append a `Charater` to a `String`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of += to append a Character to a String was intentionally deleted from the language several betas ago. Use

> puzzleOutput.append(char)

instead.